# Why do we have a c++-faq tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags

I know better than most the need for canonical questions asked daily by newbs and newcomers and the need to keep an organized list of these types of question, but is it really necessary to introduce a meta tag for it?

[c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) currently has 129 questions, out of which, 128 is also tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

This is clearly a meta-tag, it's not about the content of the question but about the nature of the question itself.

Do we have a reason to keep it alive? If we deem it worthwhile, is it worth thinking about implementing it in other tags (eg. [php-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-faq))?

Comment: From those I understand that it's fine for us to start a new [tag:php-faq] as well, since everyone (including several moderators) seem to be okay with that setup.

Comment: @SecondRikudo there are a lot of things that the c++ has done that are contrary to the norms of the site.  They reason they get away with it is they actively maintain it.  So this should not be a set it and forget it.  You need to make sure the php community is willing to put in the effort to maintain the tag and actively edit the questions to ensure they are high quality and the answers are always up-to-date

Comment: FWIW, the Python community (or the subculture that inhabits the [Python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) at least) considered a `python-faq` tag, but we opted (for now at least) to build a [separate website](http://sopython.com) to orginize the ideas and use dupe-close votes instead. There is also the tag wiki for your language tag, add in links to often-asked questions there if you need a SO-central place to stash a list.

Comment: Heavily related: [Special handling for FAQ questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168359/special-handling-for-faq-questions)