# Why do we have many [xxx-faq] tags instead of single [faq] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently on [Russian Stackoverflow](http://ru.stackoverflow.com) we had a discussion whether we should have the single [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq) tag or many dedicated tags like [python-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-faq).

Since SO has much more experience with tagging - we decided to ask it here. (Well AFAIK currently SO have [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) and [r-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-faq)).

The purpose of the "faq" tag is to gather "canonical" answers to frequently <s>closed duplicated</s> asked questions. Also reading a list of such questions might be interesting and useful for novice users.

Relevant questions are

- [Setting up a FAQ for the C++ tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252874/setting-up-a-faq-for-the-c-tag)
- [Why do we have a c++-faq tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250986/why-do-we-have-a-c-faq-tag)

Comment: Simple: the c++-faq is a meta tag. [Check this for a more through analysis](http://meta.superuser.com/q/9231/235569). Fun fact: 33 out 50 of the question in the "/frequent" tab on the c++ tag have this tag.

Comment: There are few people who are experts on faq.

Comment: @Yakk, true, but tags were invented for searching/filtering, not for getting badges on them

Comment: @Braiam: [tag:faq] by itself would be a meta-tag. [tag:c++-faq] clearly isn't.

Comment: who would watch faq?  Who would search all faqs?

Comment: @JerryCoffin what's the common topic on those questions? c++ or c++-faq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one argument against a collective [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq) tag is that there might be difficulty in attempting to treat it identically to other tags in terms of site automation.

For example, if a lot of questions eventually get tagged with [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq), it might come up as a suggested tag to users asking questions that <s>are duplicates</s> sound similar enough to frequent questions, and this is obviously something we want to prevent.

It shouldn't be added to questions by the authors, but rather by high reputation users, after a particular question has gained enough attention in its own right.

Another problem is that if users get gold badges for [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq), they'll have the ability to close questions outside their area of expertise. This is probably the biggest argument to support language/tag-specific FAQ tags, rather than a single generalized one.

Comment: "Another problem is that if users get gold badges for faq, they'll have the ability to close questions outside their area of expertise" Which is irrelevant since you need at least 200 answers on post with a tag (plus 1000 score), which is unfeasible. I prefer not having any of these tags and allow users to earn tag badges on real tags.

Comment: @Braiam that's a good point. Now that I think about it, the example I gave in the second paragraph is a reason not to use _any_ faq tag. You should probably bring that up on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363030/are-faq-tags-good