# Could we have a [google-apps-script-faq] tag similar to [c++-faq] and [r-faq]?

Tags: discussion, tags

While [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) (48,583 questions) is far away from [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (777,911 questions) and [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) (465,878 questions) (just two examples found in Similar questions suggestions from Meta Ask a question page) I think that this tag already has enough people participating regularly that might help to curate [google-apps-script-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-tag) properly.

This *-faq tag might help to make it easier to find the best original question to be used to close as duplicate and to hold guidance on how to debug / create a good "mcve"

As 2022, is there something that we should do or milestone to be reach before creating this tag?

My initial thought was that we might start by discussing about having a "How to create a mcve" for Google Apps Script and about some tag combos that might deserve to have at least one question tagged with [google-apps-script-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-faq). Besides discussing this, an early interest party (at least 3?) should work some way to "recruit" initial committers interested in prepare a "setting up a FAQ" and discuss with the SO moderators the criteria to create and maintain the tag.

Here is my proposed starting list about the tag combos:

- [[google-apps-script][google-sheets]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%5Bgoogle-sheets%5D&searchOn=3) 49,627 results
- [[google-apps-script][triggers]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%5Btriggers%5D&searchOn=3) 2,410 results
- [[google-apps-script][web-application]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%5Bweb-applications%5D&searchOn=3) 1,928 results
- [[google-apps-script][custom-function]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%5Bcustom-function%5D&searchOn=3) 787 results
- [[google-apps-script][add-on]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%5Badd-on%5D&searchOn=3) 341 results

Related

- [Setting up a FAQ for the C++ tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252874/1595451)
- [Why do we have many [xxx-faq] tags instead of single [faq] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293669/1595451)
- [Are [*-faq] tags good?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363030/1595451)

Comment: Who's gonna maintain it?  In Are [\*-faq] tags good?, the justification for *not* removing it was that it was actively maintained.

Comment: Great question @Makoto. I hope that the people that is actively participating on [tag:google-apps-script] and other related topics. I hope that they will manifest their interest and probably commitment here or in the [tag:google-apps-script] chat room.

Comment: Yeah I'm not looking for "hope".  The expectation should be that this *is* maintained, curated and kept abuse-free. If we're hoping that it won't be, then this is as good as doomed.  Some curation efforts require a lot more discipline than others for this reason.

Comment: Well that is the reason that I first posted this question instead of being bold and creating the tag by myself.

Comment: @Makoto Could we use an answer for people to write their name to show their commitment to participate in curating this *-faq tag?

Comment: You could use it to show initial interest, sure, but the folks on Meta aren't representative of the whole force of users we'd need to maintain this.  Knowing that there is some community out there willing to do something is better than finding out that there's none, and it's even better to find that out *before* you put expectations on that community.

Comment: You don't need a FAQ tag specifically, and you definitely don't need to start with that. Start by maintaining a list of FAQ (the ones you'd want to apply the tag to) in the tag wiki. If these are high-quality and oft-used as duplicate targets, they'll get "popular" and be findable, probably even more so than questions tagged [google-apps-script-faq].

Comment: I agree with creation of list of FAQs for duplicate  targets. But tag creation is another story. Just the size of the tag and number of branch tags we had to kill two years back, makes me wary of  new tag creation.

Comment: I'm not against creating the tag entirely. But I think we should explore other options first: tag wiki,  frequents tab, meta-post wiki or even a single canonical faq wiki post like [regex] does. While [c++] and [r] does have the [*-faq], many heavy weights like [python] and [js]  still doesn't. Even the counterpart [c] doesn't.

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray. It looks a good idea to start creating the FAQ list.... it looks that "saves" might help to build a private list of FAQ candidates... but AFAIK it's not possible to have a "save" in more than one list. P.S. I'm wondering if it's possible to follow a tag wiki.

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks. Definitely it will be great to work with you on looking for the best way to handle a google apps script faq

Comment: Added a initial list. I think we can start from there.

Comment: @CodyGray Is it possible to stop this question from rising to the top, if there's a edit?

Comment: @TheMaster What about using a temporary alternate place... perhaps a specific chat room or a gist and including the link in the corresponding post?

Comment: No, there's no way to do that for any question, @TheMaster. Use the [[tag:google-apps-script]] tag wiki instead, as I suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) does have the [*-faq], many heavy weights like [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js) still doesn't. And many  subject matter experts in [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) are still against it. We should explore other options first, before creating a tag straight away:

- Tag wiki
- Frequents tab
- Chat rooms
- [a single canonical faq wiki post like [regex] does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).
- External links

I dislike having to discuss site matters outside SO. I'm against External links.

Chat rooms are not especially suited for markdown lists, editing the said list and more importantly rooms gets freezed fast.

We could do [a canonical FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) like [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) did. There was a [attempt to already do this in apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336082/how-to-solve-common-errors-in-google-apps-script-development/62336083#62336083), which resulted in a [meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398230/what-to-do-with-how-to-solve-common-errors-in-google-apps-script-development), but nothing came after that. But [one of the proposals](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398234) was to create a list in the wiki.

For now, I think we should start with tag wiki. Even [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) has FAQs listed in the [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info)(which barely matches what's in their [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) suggesting it's not well maintained either[<sup>1</sup>](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363030/are-faq-tags-good/418486?noredirect=1#comment929322_418486)). I copied the initial list below to the [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info). We'll see if it works out. Discussions about what to include in the wiki can be done in the [community chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217630).

---

*A FAQ list*

[google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets)

- Timeout:

  - [Long processing time likely due to getValue and cell inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289183/long-processing-time-likely-due-to-getvalue-and-cell-inserts)
  - [Google app script timeout ~ 5 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450819/google-app-script-timeout-5-minutes)
- Setting 1D array to setValues:

  - [How do you resolve a "The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61115863/how-do-you-resolve-a-the-parameters-number-dont-match-the-method-signature)
- Dynamic dependant drop downs:

  - [How do you do dynamic / dependent drop downs in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744547/how-do-you-do-dynamic-dependent-drop-downs-in-google-sheets)
- VBA auto conversion:

  - [How to convert VBA script to Google Apps Script automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057411/how-to-convert-vba-script-to-google-apps-script-automatically)

[triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triggers)

- Testing a trigger function:

  - [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas)
- Multiple simple triggers:

  - [Merging or Combining two onEdit trigger functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602747/merging-or-combining-two-onedit-trigger-functions)

[custom-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-function):

- [Refresh data retrieved by a custom function in Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341399/refresh-data-retrieved-by-a-custom-function-in-google-sheet)

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much. P.S. I'm think that SEDE might help but I'm not use it frequently. Related questions about using SEDE to help us with this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420727/1595451

Comment: I think creating a FAQ in the tag wiki is the best way to go overall. Though regarding this tag wiki, I would suggest to clean it up and remove any posting advice that's generic to all SO posts. "How to ask a good question on SO" or "How to create a minimal reproducible example" has no business getting posted inside the google-apps-script wiki. However, the tag usage guidance about reading official resources first is good and tag-specific, as are any advise about which tags to use in combination with google-apps-script.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the inputs. "How to ask" is present in many tags including [js wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info). Apps script has a very low entry bar and attracts newbie and "gimme teh codez" questions regularly. I have a canned reply  with a link to the tag info page for resources/ask guidance, when closing such questions. But I guess we could try to tailor the "how to ask" more specific to this tag.

Comment: @TheMaster New users won't read the tag wiki - if we are lucky they read the tag except, but that's rare. So the tag wiki is more about establishing consensus among veteran users regarding how a tag should be used, for example in case users are uncertain how to moderate a certain tag. Or in case of the FAQ - to find a place where veteran users quickly can go and grab a canonical dupe to use as duplicate target. Or share their personal bookmark collection of canonical dupes with others, instead of having every individual who is moderating a tag hoarding their own private link collection.

Comment: @Lundin I agree they won't. I was just keeping it for my canned reply: *Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.*  Sidenote: "Saves" could've easily closed this gap, if it could be shared among users.

Comment: @TheMaster Including a bunch of standard user moderator replies specific to a tag might not be such a bad idea, as long as they are specific to the tag. I'm not sure if any other tags do this though - I haven't seen it. Some tag wikis do include user moderation guidelines, however.