# Canonical question for TypeError Cannot [call method / read property / set property] of null in Google Apps Script

Tags: discussion, canonical, community-wiki

Tl;Dr: In the last few days three community members are working around the tag wiki of [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script). The goal is to have a "FAQ". This question is specific to make a FAQ about few TypeError messages in [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) :

```
TypeError: Cannot call method ... of null
TypeError: Cannot read property ... of null
TypeError: Cannot set properties ... of null
```

---

- `[google-apps-script] title:typeerror cannot "of null"`returns 59 results
- `[google-apps-script] -title:typeerror is:question cannot "of null"` returns 226 results
- `[google-apps-script]  "TypeError: Cannot" is:question` 887 results

Please propose the initial content for a Q/A about these errors as an answer to this question. If you want to make more than one proposal, i.e. proposing to review two or more existing questions, use one answer for each proposal.

Proposals of [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) questions that doesn't require the use of framework or library are welcome.

---

Google Apps Script uses JavaScript as programming language but it doesn't support some features and doesn't support most of the [Web API's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) commonly used with JavaScript like [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model). Considering this I think that most of frequent questions on [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) aren't appropriate for [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script).

In other words, "vanilla javascript" like answers that marginally use  something extra might be easily applied in Google Apps Script projects. Answers that require the use of frameworks with specialized vocabulary / practices is very unlikely that could not be applied in this platform, i.e. Google Apps Script doesn't support `import`, `export`(`Promise`, `async`/ `await` syntax is supported, but only works synchronously), also Google Apps Script web apps have some restrictions for client-side code.

[google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) has a lot of questions trying to get a `SpreadsheetApp.Sheet` object but the method used returns null, i.e. because the sheet name was was misspelled, the sheet was renamed, etc. Something similar happens with other Google Apps Script services (CalendarApp, ContactsApp, DocsApp, DriveApp, FormsApp, SlidesApp, etc.)

As happens with other platforms, the explanation about what is and why it happens and how it's fixed in broad terms is the same, just the way to reproduce the problem and debug it might differ a bit because the use of an online Editor IDE and the JavaScript supported features, less frequently depends on the specific Google Apps Script service used.

As happens in other tags, the OP's usually didn't included a "mcve". Also there is no real value to have a lot questions where the only significant difference are the variable names.

---

Sample questions by Google Apps Script service and method returning null.

[google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets)

- `SpreadsheetApp.getSpreadsheetById(spreadsheeId)`, `.getActiveSpreadsheet()`, `.getActive()` might return `null`.

  - [TypeError: Cannot call method "getActiveSheet" of null. at myFunction(Code:6)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56741432/1595451) (h/t TheMaster)
  - [Accessing spreadsheet in Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12990637/1595451)
- `SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName)` might return null

  - [How to fix 'TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null' in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56690325/1595451) (h/t TheMaster)

[google-docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-docs)

- `DocumentsApp.getActiveDocument().getHeader()` might return null

  - [Trying to get folder path of file in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62377259/1595451)

[google-calendar-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar-api)

- `CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId)` returns null if the user hasn't access to the calendar or there isn't a calendar with the value of `calendarId`

  - [Not able to create event on Calendar with this script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71354741/1595451)
  - [Access rights missing for CalendarApp - createEvent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73187146/1595451)

---

Related

- [What should we do with "How to solve common errors in Google Apps Script development"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398230/1595451)
- [Could we have a [google-apps-script-faq] tag similar to [c++-faq] and [r-faq]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420721/1595451)

Comment: `Considering this I think that most of frequent questions on javascript aren't appropriate for google-apps-script.` This is only true, where the web apis are used. Considering this specific question, there is no specific webapi usage and [js] questions are valid duplicates. But I cannot find a canonical in [js] for this error either.

Comment: Just found this: [How to resolve TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29721205/1595451) but I don't think that will work as [tag:google-apps-script] FAQ for most of the questions as it's about replicating `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Nice find. Agree it won't work as a dupe target. This is getting harder than I imagined.

Comment: "Web API" is (was?) somewhat ambiguous due to "[Web API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework#Apache_License_2.0_release)", a Microsoft invasion (yes, often the exact same spelling is used in many contexts, possibly as a shorthand for "ASP.NET Web API". [Sample](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-web-api-razor-and-open-source)).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks (for the edits and the comment). Edited (Web API's commonly used with JavaScript and added a link pointing to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API

Comment: But the reasons for the error occurring are the same in JavaScript or [google-apps-script] (which IINM is just an SDK on top of JavaScript); You're trying to get/set a property on undefined, which doesn't have those. Not sure why it makes sense to create more confusion by having different sets of canonicals. For instance, "google-apps-script has a lot of questions trying to get a SpreadsheetApp.Sheet object but the method used returns null, i.e. because the sheet name was was misspelled, the sheet was renamed, etc." Same thing happens with DOM selection `getElement(s)By*` and the like.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for you reply. Please suggest a canonical question that work "universally".

Comment: Ugh, those questions get asked about once an hour. [27,798 and counting](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+typeerror+cannot+read+property)....

Comment: Are you sure that we only need one canonical?

Comment: What about one of [views:500000](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+typeerror+cannot+read+property+views%3A500000) ?(there are only 5)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Is there something more vanilla? Which doesn't depend on the browser apis or jquery or react, but something that depends on plain objects or arrays?

Comment: I think that's perfection getting in the way of good. Any question asked here is going to depend on an object with a property. Does it matter if that's a DOM object, a jQuery object, a React object, or a "plain" object? I mean, jQuery and React objects are "plain" objects that just happen to be defined within libraries...

Comment: There are a lot of things that could be done in Google Apps Script without DOM, jQuery, React or other front-end fancy things... better to avoid having to explain them.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Edited the question Tl;Dr "vanilla javascript" like canonical questions are welcome / might be helpful. Questions that make use of frameworks that can't be answered using "vanilla javascript" are very unlikely that will be helpful as a canonical for Google Apps Script questions.

Comment: @HereticMonkey That's fair. But Problem is reproducibility. A newbie pointed to one of these questions cannot reproduce the solution or the question code in Apps script environment. Hence, making major part of the solution useless. Theoretically, they can help, but we're not providing practical solution by closing them as duplicates. On the other hand, questions like these can be used to close, because they're reproducible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript%20arrays?sort=MostFrequent&edited=true

Comment: Apps script is server side Javascript and no one really cares about front end of things. Though based on v8, just like [nodejs], we specifically lack `import`, `export` support. Therefore [nodejs type error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnodejs%5D+typeerror+cannot+read+property) may not be useful either.

Comment: Perhaps this new question might fit the bill :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/74103470/215552

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks. It quickly is getting feedback, that is really great... I think that I will be able to add my own a bit later.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Posted your "FAQ proposal" as answer to provide feedback considering *this context*. P.S. Wondering if it could be convenient to add a link to this question and/or metione that it's a "FAQ proposal".

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
Self-answered question posted and set as community wiki:
[Reference : TypeError: Cannot read property [property name here] from undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74109026/1595451)

---

## Question

<sup>Posted as Community Wikis [Reference : TypeError: Cannot read property [property name here] from undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74109026/1595451)</sup>

### Title

**Reference : TypeError: Cannot read property [property name here] from undefined**

### Body

- Why the [Execution order of GS files in a Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687907/execution-order-of-gs-files-in-a-project) causes `TypeError: Cannot read property "sayName" from undefined.`?
- [Testing a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16089041/1595451) causes `ReferenceError: 'e' is not defined.` or `TypeError: Cannot read property *...* from undefined`
- [TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18947556/1595451)
- [Google Script send form values by email, error: cannot read property "namedValues"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28997714/1595451)
  <sup>Not enough details from the OP but three different answers that for different scenarios</sup>
- [TypeError: Cannot call method "getName" of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43917978/1595451)
- [TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined (line 3, file "Code"). I have a trigger for on form submit and yet it still has an error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74104563/1595451)<sup>Missing character in property name (OP used value instead of values)</sup>

### Tags

[google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)[typeerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typeerror)[undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undefined)

## Answer

<sup>Posted as community wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74109027/1595451</sup>

Extract from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62336083

**Message**

> TypeError: Cannot read property '`property name here`' from `undefined (or null)`

<sup>Move to the question title; make specific about `undefined`</sup>

**Description**

The error message indicates that you are trying to access a property on an `Object` instance, but during *runtime* the value *actually* held by a variable is a special data type `undefined`. Typically, the error occurs when accessing *nested* properties of an object.

A variation of this error with a numeric value in place of property name indicates that an instance of `Array` was expected. As arrays in JavaScript are [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), everything mentioned here is true about them as well.

There is a special case of *dynamically constructed* objects such as [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) that are only available in specific contexts like making an HTTP request to the app or invoking a function via time or event-based trigger.

> The error is a [TypeError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError) because an `"object"` is expected, but `"undefined"` is received

**How to fix**

1. **Using default values**
   [Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) `||` operator in JavaScript has an interesting property of evaluating the right-hand side of the left-hand is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). Since objects in JS are truthy, and `undefined` and `null` are falsy, an expression like `(myVar || {}).myProp` [`(myVar || [])[index]` for arrays] will guarantee that no error is thrown and the property is at least `undefined`.

   One can also provide default values: `(myVar || { myProp : 2 })` guarantees accessing `myProp` to return `2` by default. Same goes for arrays: `(myVar || [1,2,3])`.
2. **Checking for type**
   Especially true for the special case,  `typeof` [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) combined with an `if` [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) and a [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) will either allow a function to run outside of its designated context (i.e. for debugging purposes) or introduce branching logic depending on whether the object is present or not.

   One can control how strict the check should be:

   - lax ("not undefined"): `if(typeof myVar !== "undefined") { //do something; }`
   - strict ("proper objects only"): `if(typeof myVar === "object" && myVar) { //do stuff }`
3. **[Arrays] length property being greater than the numeric value**<sup>Added</sup>

Array.prototype.length returns the number of elements of the Array. This number always should be greater than the numeric value (aka index) as JavaScript uses 0 based indices.

**Related Q&As**

<s>1. [Parsing order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687907/execution-order-of-gs-files-in-a-project) of the GAS project as the source of the issue</s><sup>Move to the question body</sup>

Comment: The description should be extended to include common cases in [tag:google-apps-script] i.e. `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet 1')` returned `null` as well the "how to fix" that might be to use the correct sheet name.

Comment: I think it's important to realize `null` is not `undefined` and the errors shouldn't be merged. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript  Unlike undefined, `null` is "assigned" on purpose. `null` in apps script is almost exclusively related to sheet name, while others are related to  undefined variables, which this answer explains.  For null, I propose https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56690325/ or something specific

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks. I agree with you ... `null` is no `undefine` /  TypeError + null  and TypeError + undefined very likely deserve their own FAQ, actually TypeError + undefined might require more than one, i.e. we already have [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16089041/1595451) and others

Comment: I'm wondering whether there are significant amount of questions outside of [triggers] `e` Type error to warrant another FAQ for "TypeError + undefined." Typeerror +null other than sheetname, is related to Spreadsheet being null: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56741432/typeerror-cannot-call-method-getactivesheet-of-null-at-myfunctioncode6

Comment: I have lot of suggestions, but I think it can be directly made to question after it is posted to [main]

Comment: @TheMaster Posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74109026/1595451. I'm not sure about the process to mark the question as Wiki... I know that it should be flagged to mod but not sure what the flag report should be made after certain participation level

Comment: I think a link to this meta should be enough to get community wiki.

Answer (score 2):

I think that we might have a *reference* question for Google Apps Script classes like `CalendarApp`, `ContactsApp`, `DocumentsApp`, `GmailApp`, `SpreadsheetApp`, `SlidesApp`, that access end-user Google resources through Google user accounts.

By resources I mean, files stored in Google Drive, calendars and events from Google Calendars, contacts from Google Contacts, emails from Gmail, probably groups (emailing lists) from Google Groups, etc.

Some of the services might return `null` if the user hasn't access to the resource or if part of the resource, i.e. a sheet in a spreadsheet, doesn't match the parameter used, i.e. the sheet name.

---

There are some questions that might include `TypeError: Cannot... undefined` but the cause of the problem is having received `null`, like in the following case

- [TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30722485/1595451) caused by `GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(something).getThreads()` returned `null`, then the code "built" a 2d Array, the called something like `arr.length` and `arr[0].length` as `SpreasheetApp.Sheet.getRange` parameters

---

The focus might be the basics of how [access-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-control) works for this types of resources how the parts might be retrieved, how to debug `TypeError: Cannot ... of null` (i.e. how to check the that a sheet name is correct) and known problems like using Google accounts multiple sign-in might cause that Google Apps Script use the credentials of an unexpected account and to provide guidance on how to create a "mcve" in case that question authors require further help.

This reference question/answer might be included in the canonical questions for each app if they are really needed.

---

Question about Apps Script issues with multiple Sign-in

- [Wrong account displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62724029/1595451)
- [Apps Script google.script.run does not work within a Library-bound html file when triggered by other users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68911474/1595451)
- [Apps Script google.script.run does not work within a Library-bound html file when triggered by other users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68911474/1595451)
- [I can't open my Web App Link on Google App Scripts when multiple Gmail accounts logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69684594/1595451)

---

Sample *reference* questions

- [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1595451)
- [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1595451)
- [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/1595451)

Answer (score 2):

Posted a proposed FAQ<sup>[1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420764/canonical-question-for-typeerror-cannot-call-method-read-property-set-prope?noredirect=1#comment930395_420764)</sup> here to provide feedback about using it *in this context* ([google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) questions ) either as *reference* (link in comments / answers) or as *original* (close as duplicate)

Source: [How to solve TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74103470/1595451) (rev 1)

## Question

Some simple code that I feel should work:

```js
function getUser(id) {
  // get user from DB
  var user;
  return user;
}

var user = getUser(1);

var uid = user.getId();

console.log(uid);
```

The error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getId')

What is going on?

---

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74103471/1595451 (rev 1)

## Answer

The function that is supposed to be setting `user` to an object with a `getId()` method is instead returning `undefined`. That value does not have any properties or methods, so it throws the error shown.

There are several ways around the error, but it comes down to deciding what you want to do when `getUser` returns `undefined`. You can throw a different, more informative error. Either at the time you know you didn't get a `User` back from `getUser(1)`:

```js
class User {
  #id = 1;
  constructor() {}
  get id() {
    return this.#id;
  }
  set id(value) {
    this.#id = value;
  }
  getId() {
    return this.id;
  }
}

function getUser(id) {
  // get user from DB
  var user;
  return user;
}

var user = getUser(1);

if (!(user instanceof User)) {
  throw new Error(`The value returned from getUser(1): ${JSON.stringify(user)} was not a User.`);
}

var uid = user.getId();

console.log(uid);
```

Or later, via [the "optional chaining" operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```js
class User {
  #id = 1;
  constructor() {}
  get id() {
    return this.#id;
  }
  set id(value) {
    this.#id = value;
  }
  getId() {
    return this.id;
  }
}

function getUser(id) {
  // get user from DB
  var user;
  return user;
}

var user = getUser(1);

var uid = user?.getId();

if (isNaN(uid)) {
  throw new Error(`The value returned from getUser(1).getId(): ${JSON.stringify(uid)} was not a number.`);
}

console.log(uid);
```

You can also just choose to pass the problem on to the next consumer. So, assuming the code is part of a tautological `getUserId(userId)` function, you could pass the undefined on, again, via our friend the optional chaining operator `?.`.

```js
class User {
  #id = 1;
  constructor() {}
  get id() {
    return this.#id;
  }
  set id(value) {
    this.#id = value;
  }
  getId() {
    return this.id;
  }
}

function getUser(id) {
  // get user from DB
  var user;
  return user;
}

function getUserId(id) {
  var user = getUser(id);
  var uid = user?.getId();
  return uid;
}

console.log(getUserId(1));
```

Comment: IMHO most of the questions that might be closed as duplicate were posted by people that are new to Google Apps Script / JavaScript. Considering this, I think that terms like "consumer" and "tautological" might be convenient to be explained or to include a reference. By the other hand the optional chaining operator isn't supported in Google Apps Script. Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64346434/1595451 (include a link to Apps Script issue marked as "Won't fix", apparently it's not supported in [tag:v8])

Comment: <s>I don't know if `#` is supported in Apps Script</s> `#` prefix isn't supported in Apps Script. Ref. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/239767510#comment2.  Related [Are private class properties supported in Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73055980/1595451), [What does the '#' sign mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10899448/1595451)

Comment: I edited my answer there as soon as I got a upvote. I know that chaining with all other latest features is working for the past few months. We should also edit the SO answer to use optional chaining in favor of logical OR `||`

Comment: A busy morning, eh! :)  Thanks. I'm wondering if  nullish coalescing operator (`??`) might be an option (found thanks to the MDN ?. article "see also" section, <sidenote> I'll be away form SO for several hours</sidenote>)

Comment: Null coalescing also works. I didn't test it today. It's been a few days(months?), that I've known that it's indeed working. Google upgrades the underlying v8 engine regularly without any notifications to us.

Comment: I can run the examples in Google Chrome & Node, which uses V8, so all of this is available in V8. Whether it's available in Google Apps Script is a different matter. My main concern was not the syntax, but just getting an example out there. I've made some changes to it since posting. Feel free to edit it (I've asked to make it a CW also).

Comment: @HereticMonkey  "Google Apps Script" is in the question title, as well that it was mentioned multiple times, so it's fair to say that basic premise is that Google Apps Script deserves a canonical question about the referred error. I don't say that your self-answered question is bad, just that as it was the last time I saw it, it is not what we are looking for here.

Comment: @Rubén I understand that. But my purpose for the question was not to serve Google Apps Script, but the larger JavaScript community. And there's no reason the question can't serve both communities, since Google Apps Script runs on JavaScript, and answering the question sufficiently broadly will be of use to both. I'm not sure why people are getting hung up on the syntax of ancillary objects that are just there to frame the question.

Answer (score 0):

## Question

<sup>Taken from [TypeError when trying to use getRange](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71631629/1595451)</sup>

### Title

TypeError when trying to use getRange

### Body

NOTE: This is a proposal of canonical Q/A

As a new Google Apps Script user, I'm struggling about how to fix this error

This happen when using the default runtime

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null

This happen when using the old runtime

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null.

Bounded project

```
function myFunction(){
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('my sheet');
  sheet.getRange('A1');
}
```

Standalone project

```
function myFunction(){
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('put_here_a_spreadsheet_url');
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('my sheet');
  sheet.getRange('A1');
}
```

Using `getActiveSpredsheet()` and getRange directly from the `spreadsheet` variable

```
function myFunction(){
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1');
}
```

### Tags

[google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)[google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets)[typeerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typeerror)[null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/null)

## Answer

<sup>Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/71631630/1595451</sup>

The error occurs because the spreadsheet hasn't a sheet named `my sheet`. Please bear in mind that the `getSheetByName` parameter should be exactly the same as the sheet name:

- Same number of characters
- Same casing (uppercase / lowercase)
- The characters not only should look the same way, they should be the same i.e. a space looks similar to the human eye as a non-breaking-space but for the computers they aren't the same.

You might try typing the sheet name again both on the Google Sheets UI and on the Google Apps Script editor, or copy the name from one place and paste it into the other.

NOTE: You could use a variable name or put the sheet name directly inside the parenthesis. If you go for putting the sheet name inside the parenthesis it should be enclosed between `'` (apostrophe / straight single quote), `"` (straight double quote) or `` ` `` (grave accent / backtick).

The same error might happen when using `getActiveSpreadsheet()` or `getActiveSheet()` there is no active spreadsheet or active sheet
respectively. This usually happen when using these methods on stand-alone projects. In these cases, first you have to open the spreadsheet by using one of the following SpreadsheetApp methods `open(file)`, `openById(id)`, `openByUrl(url)`, then you might use `.activate()` before `getActiveSpreadsheet()` / `getActiveSheet()` methods.

Resources

- [Handling text — strings in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings)

Related (from oldest to newest)

- [JDBC Reading from a Database... TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 9)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13002218/)
- [Can't get Google Scripts working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22367010/)
- [TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 20, file "Code")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52357590/)
- [Issue with protection script for google sheets - Cannot read property 'getRange' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62112801/)
- [TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (line 6, file "Code") in google sheet script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62828787/)
- [TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (line 14, file "Code")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62887346/)
- [TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null deleteRows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67228069/)
- [Issue with protection script for google sheets - Cannot read property 'getRange' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62112801/)